# How can I tell if a VM is on Xen 6 hypervisor

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

How can I tell if a virtual guest is on a Xen 6 hypervisor using the REST API https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/.json?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

nope that information is not available via API, you could submit an item and ask the softlaer's employess for that information.

Regards