# Relation datatype not working SoftLayer API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to fetch processor,network,hypervisor,physical details of VM's through SoftLayer API unfortunately relational datatypes are not working. Referring to the following link
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/#controlPanel

When i tried using host datatype doesn't throw any error rather no result regarding host information

Contacted SoftLayer through ticket and they don't provide much support for SoftLayer API. Suggested to post queries here.

Answer (score 0):

The control panel relational datatype is working correctly, if you do not obtain any result you may not have ordered this item in your VM, the host relational datatype is not working it seems a SoftLayer issue, you can report this issue by opening a SoftLayer ticket.

You can use this rest api to get the details of a VM such as its physical parts and its software.

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[virtualGuestId]/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,allowedHost[credential],backendNetworkComponents[ipAddressBindings,primarySubnet[networkVlan[primaryRouter[datacenter]]]],bandwidthAllocation,billingItem[id,item],blockDevices[device,diskImage[capacity,localDiskFlag,type.name,billingItem.categoryCode,units],mountType],datacenter[id,longName,name],dedicatedAccountHostOnlyFlag,dedicatedHost[backendRouter, id, name],domain,firewallServiceComponent,frontendNetworkComponents[ipAddressBindings,primaryVersion6IpAddressRecord,primarySubnet[networkVlan[dedicatedFirewallFlag,networkVlanFirewall,primaryRouter[datacenter]]]],fullyQualifiedDomainName,globalIdentifier,hostname,hourlyBillingFlag,lastOperatingSystemReload,lastPowerStateId,localDiskFlag,maxCpu,maxCpuUnits,maxMemory,monitoringServiceComponent,networkComponents[subnets],networkVlans.firewallInterfaceCount,postInstallScriptUri,primaryBackendIpAddress,primaryIpAddress,primaryNetworkComponent,privateNetworkOnlyFlag,provisionDate,softwareComponents[passwords[createDate,modifyDate,notes,password,username],softwareLicense[softwareDescription[features.keyName,manufacturer,name,operatingSystem,version]]],startCpus,status,statusId,type,uuid]
```

Reference:

https://softlayer.github.io/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/

Comment: Thanks Ojeda!! Yes correct control panel is working was able to pull the result. I'm looking for host relational datatype and it's not working. Created a ticket with SoftLayer here is the response from them "Thank you for reaching out to us, Shaik. I am afraid that we cannot do much support of the API through ticket and through chat or the phone. The best way to get help is to go to the github forums and then tag Softlayer in it and our devs can help you out. " Can you help me is there any other way to get the hypervisor,physical details of VM

Comment: Did you try the rest api that I sent you above, it will retrieve the physical and software details for your VM the same information that you can see by the control portal. About the hypervisor information is not available via API. For more reference see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43159952/how-can-i-tell-if-a-vm-is-on-xen-6-hypervisor

Comment: Yes. i tried the above rest api but don't find the physical details like  Manufacturer of the CPU, Hardware type of the CPU,Serial number of the CPU,Manufacturer of the NETWORK,Hardware type of the NETWORK, Serial number of the NETWORK. Can you please to pull the same. Would be great. Much appreciated!!! Thanks Ojeda!!!

Comment: You can get by API all the information that you see in the control portal. The information that you want about the VM items such as serial, manufacture, etc. you do not see in the control portal, so by api it is the same.